# Android SQLite - openOrCreateDatabase() nullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following DBAdapter (this isn't all of it, but it's the relevant code).

```
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "seller";
private final String DATABASE_MY_TABLE = "sellertable";
private final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1
private final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE seller ........";

public DBAdapter( Context c )
{
    this.context = c;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DatabaseHelper( Context context )
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db )
    {
        MyLog.d("Creating Tables");
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion )
    {
        MyLog.w("Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ". Destroying old data.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_MY_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// Opens the database
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

When I try to `db.open()` I get the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.company.app.MyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
    at com.company.app.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:74)
    at com.company.app.MyApp.<init>(MyApp.java:106)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
```

It appears it's getting some kind of exception, related to when the helper is deciding whether or not to create or update the database...

Comment: It's just a constant for "seller". Sorry I didn't throw in all my constants, I'll add what I need to the above code.

Comment: This is almost definitely caused by the passed in `Context` being `null` -- there's nothing else in [`ContextWrapper.java:203`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Candroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) that could cause an NPE.

Comment: I believe that ended up being the problem, Philipp. If you want to answer properly down below I will give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an extension like ".db" to the end of your database name.

Comment: Well I fixed it some other way.. I'm not sure what I did. I think it was a context problem. I guess the application context never got passed to the DBAdapter or something... What is the deal with the .db added to the end of the name? Is that a known fix or is that the recommended way to name them?

Comment: It's just the way I was always taught. I don't know that it has significance if the file system doesn't care that there's no extension. The database name is, after, just a file name.

Comment: as suggested above, better put .db

Comment: It's a convention. It doesn't affect anything code-was as long as you're using the same name.

Comment: be sure to see the real answer by @JoePlante

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this, probably for a different reason. I tried doing something db-related that involved a context before onCreate() got called. Hope this helps someone out there

Comment: This is the reason. The accepted answer is confounded. The problem is evident from the question's stacktrace: database being opened in `MyApp.<init>` i.e. member variable initialization, well before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the exact problem is for Context then, I can suggest on it as I faced the same issue yesterday.

Suppose I am calling **DatabaseHelper** from other class then I had to provide the context. I was confused about which context:
1. getApplicationContext()
2. getBaseContext()
3. instance of a Context which has been initialized in the constructor of the class which was calling DatabaseHelper object i.e _context.

But the actual solution which I got was to use **this**

For Example:-

DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(**this**);