# openorcreatedatabase gives nullpointerexception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

i used databases before in the android app i am working on
so usualy i open() the database 
when my query is finished i close() it again

with my latest change to my database class i get an error
giving following traces

```
  02-23 14:27:55.261: I/webserver do in background(23728): bezoek = [Ljava.lang.String;@40e324a0
02-23 14:27:55.261: D/AndroidRuntime(23728): Shutting down VM
02-23 14:27:55.261: W/dalvikvm(23728): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.ABezoeAdapter$dbhulp.<init>(ABezoeAdapter.java:60)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.ABezoeAdapter.open(ABezoeAdapter.java:87)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.AWebServAdapter.synchroniseren(AWebServAdapter.java:186)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten.handlescan(bezoekrapporten.java:146)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten$1.onEditorAction(bezoekrapporten.java:68)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5314)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5204)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:353)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-23 14:27:55.311: E/AndroidRuntime(23728):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this errors occure since i have changed this part of code

```
public void gegevensupdaten(String bezoeknummer, String[] data) {
            Log.i("AbezoeAdapter gegevensupdaten", "bezoeknummer= " + bezoeknummer + "gegevens = " + data);
            open();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(bezoekrapportdatum, data[2]);
            cv.put(herstellingsoort, data[3]);


            Log.i("test","gelukt");


            onzedatabase.update(databasetabel, cv,  bezoekrapportnummer + "=?", new String[] {bezoeknummer});
            sluit();
            return;
        }
```

the error occures at the moment of calling the function open()
but this function is open as it is always used before i reach this part of code (and at that moment it doesn't block)

my open() method looks like:

```
private static class dbhulp extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    dbhulp(Context context) {
        super(context, ADbAdapter.databasenaam, null, ADbAdapter.databaseversie);
        getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i("abezoe dbhulp", "dbhulp goed doorbracht");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ADbAdapter.onCreate(db);
        Log.i("adbadapter", "oncreate opgeroepen");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        ADbAdapter.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        Log.i("adbadapter", "onupgrade opgeroepen");


    }



}
public ABezoeAdapter(Context c){
    onzecontext = c;
}

public ABezoeAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    onzehelper = new dbhulp(onzecontext);
    onzedatabase = onzehelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i("abezoeadapter open", "gelukt");
    return this;
}

public void sluit(){
    onzehelper.close();

}
```

hours of searching on the internet learned me that i am not the only one running against this error but nobody seems to provide a good sollution for my problem
thanks for your help in advance

**EDIT:**
i just found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957991/android-sqlite-openorcreatedatabase-nullpointerexception) that probably deals about the same problem

but i don't understand the answer given:

> "This is the reason. The accepted answer is confounded. The problem
>   is evident from the question's stacktrace: database being opened in
>   MyApp. i.e. member variable initialization, well before
>   onCreate(). –  laalto Dec 29 '13 at 7:31"

can anybody help to understand my failure?

Comment: You are correct - that post answers your problem. You're trying to use the DB with a context that hasn't been initialized yet. How and when do you initialize the `ABezoeAdapter` object in use? And how and when are you calling its `gegevensupdaten` function?

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace says the `Context` you passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` was `null`.

The code doesn't show how you initialize your `ABezoeAdapter` where the `Context` comes from but that's where you should be looking to solve the problem.

Comment: your answer came just to late, i solved my problem already, thanks anyway! Do you know maybe why the context of the "3th" class is not valid for the databaseactions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a crystal ball to remotely view your code. Common reasons for `Context` problems like this include e.g. 1) using fragment `getActivity()` too early in the fragment lifecycle 2) using uninitialized member variables 3) calling `getBaseContext()` or such before the activity has been prepared to be used as a `Context` (before `onCreate()`)

Comment: i used ABezoeAdapter bezoe = new ABezoeAdapter(this); to pass the context from request activity to ABezoeAdapter as executing activity, now this seems to work in one activity but not in the other

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem!! (happy modus)

i had called the function gegevensupdaten() from my 3th class AWebServerAdapter

there seems to be something wrong with the context of that class to be able to do databaseactions with my 2nd(Abezoeadapter) class

so i returned the data from webserver to my main(1st,bezoekrapporten) class and called gegevensupdaten() from my 1st class

why this context of 3th class doesn't work is still a mystery for me